# Do mutations occur while growing virus for preparing inactivated viral vaccine?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, virus

The development of mutations in virus is reported to happen [during replication](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-02544-6), especially for an mRNA type virus like SARS-COV-2

> Viruses that encode their genome in RNA, such as SARS-CoV-2, HIV and
> influenza, tend to pick up mutations quickly as they are copied inside
> their hosts, because enzymes that copy RNA are prone to making errors

My question is does the same mutations occur while mass manufacturing inactivated viral vaccines?

Simply because the process of manufacturing inactivated vaccines replicate the virus in large quantities, there might be large number of mutations occurring. Will this make each batch different from one another?
Or do they control the replication process to limit the mutations?

Comment: Cross-posted on Biology.SE: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/101318/948